# Change the macros to pick separate definition according to hash_map key type

Tags: c++, hashmap, macros

I have an interesting problem to deal with STL hash maps.

Consider this in my code :

```
HSH_table(char*, obj_a) hash_1;
char* a = "abc";
char* b = "abc";
```

And I am doing a typedef of HSH_table somewhere in .h files.

```
#define HSH_table(Key, Data)  __gnu_cxx::hash_map(Key, Data)
```

Problem with __gnu_cxx::hash_map is that it does not work well with char*. If two char* are same(not the pointer, its values) then it shouldn't insert at same slot. In this scenario, both a and b should go to the same slot since they share the same value. Is that correct? I see that default behaviour is that it inserts both pointers at different slots due to their pointer different.

I do not want to change my source code but I can change the .h file. In case I want to insert at the same slot, we might need to write a comparator function. I want the comparator function-specific only to one key, i.e. char*.

Something like this:

```
#define HSH_table(Key, Data) \
  if (key == <char*>) { \
    __gnu_cxx::hash_map(Key, Data, Comparator) \
  else \
    __gnu_cxx::hash_map(Key, Data)
```

First, is it possible?

If yes, then what should we write so that it takes char* as different and everything else as different. What would the right way match char* which is an macro argument.

Comment: First of all, [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) is not the [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library). Secondly, why do you use the non-portable `__gnu_cxx::hash_map` instead of [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which is a hashed associative container.

Comment: As for the problems with pointers for a key, for strings that's usually solved by using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) as the key.

Comment: I don't understand that code at all. When did templates become macros?

Comment: By other words, declare `hash_1` as `std::unordered_map<std::string, obj_a>`.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the following:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value> struct hash_map_alias
{
    using type = std::unordered_map<Key, Value>;
};

// Provide special comparer for C-string
template <typename Value> struct hash_map_alias<const char*, Value>
{
    using type = std::unordered_map<Key, Value, StringComparer>;
};
template <typename Value> struct hash_map_alias<char*, Value>
{
    using type = std::unordered_map<Key, Value, StringComparer>;
};

// And now your MACRO
#define HSH_table(Key, Data)  typename hash_map_alias<Key, Data>::type
```